# To what are humans from one world allergic to humans from another?

Tags: biology, biochemistry, bio-mechanics, medical

Assume that there are two types of humans. One is your bog standard Earth like. The other is slightly biologically different. A few extra glands and hormones, maybe even an extra organ. The differences aren't big enough to cause genetic incompatibility when it comes to having children between these two groups.

The humans who are packed with extra organs however have a chance at being allergic to Earth like humans. It can range from sniffles to anaphylaxis if they aren't medicated. The reverse is **NOT** true. With enough medicine some of these people can acclimate to Earth like humans. The planet of these extra organed humans is polluted and a semi opaque cloud covers large portions of the sky.

**To what would these humans with extra organs be allergic to Earth like humans?**

The allergy has to relate to something intrinsic to Earth like humans. Not the enviornment. Meaning even if they meet in a clean room that's been filtered, the extra organed human is going to have a bad time if they are allergic.

Edit:

Both humans have originated from Earth, but colonization efforts over a long time have allowed for some natural and human forced evolution on other planets. From a timeline point of view perspective, one can expect a divergence between the two humans at around the early pre-Roman era. Meaning that humans on Earth changed in so far as we expect and observe today. While the humans on another planet changed differently such that they could adapt to its environment.

Comment: VTC, the question is too vague & seems more like it's meant for idea generation than answering a specific problem.

Comment: @FIRES_ICE    It may be irritating to some that you don't mention the origin of the difference between Earth humans and the other humans.  Where did those "other" humans come from?

Comment: "Why would they be allergic" or "to what would they be allergic"? The first one is up to you, the second one we can help with. (Meanwhile, through association, I have [my favourite Placebo song](https://youtu.be/wJB0c7sAcbw) stuck in my head.)

Comment: @OT-64SKOT Would listing an allergy narrow scope enough? Or as Joachim notes, posing "to what would they be allergic to?"

Comment: @FIRES_ICE p robably

Answer (score 2):

They may be **allergic not to humans, but to things that humans shed**: hair for example, or dead skin cells. Or to mites and similar life forms which feed on these human sheddings. Or to the feces of these mites.

Answer (score 1):

Why not?

There are already many people who are allergic to others. Sometimes to saliva, sometimes to sperm, sometimes to woman fluids. Your humans can simply be allergic to dead skin cells. If that's not enough then you can think about allergies to fungi and bacteria which live on human skin.

Too many vectors here.

Do you even need to explain what they are allergic to? Maybe stay with just a description of the symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

You could use that extra organ.

They may not be allergic to humans but to the air humans breathe. If they live on a more polluted world and they have an extra organ. Then that organ could be a cleanser, like the kidneys.

Earth air it too pure for the extra organ humans. This causes the organ to stop working properly. They start to get sick as the organ basically dies.(I do want to mention that I am not a biologist or scientist in any way and this may be all wrong and impossible). You can think of it like lung disease but with air that is too good instead of cigarette smoke.

Comment: OP did state they don't want the cause to be environmental, so that it can happen anywhere with humans, rather than being constrained to certain locations

Comment: @MS Then I did not pay attention.